# Can we rotate camera/viewport on Flame with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flame

I have a case that requires to rotate the camera or viewport (instead of component) on Flame on Flutter. Is Flame's camera implementation able to do that now? I cannot find any source regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the camera system that is built-in to `FlameGame` it isn't possible, but you can rotate the canvas in the `FlameGame` if you override the `renderTree` method.

With the new `CameraComponent` API it should be possible however, what you have to do then is to set the angle of the `Viewfinder`.
https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.1.1/flame/camera_component.html#viewfinder

Comment: How can I incorporste CemeraComponent by the way? From the link you provided seems like rather a conceptual. Thanks again!

Comment: You can have a look at this example and its code (go to the code by pressing <> in the upper right corner).
https://examples.flame-engine.org/#/Camera%20%26%20Viewport_CameraComponent